# PHP: How to hide/display chunks of HTML

Tags: php, html

I'm hoping someone can help with this very newbie question. I've just come from an ASP.Net environment where it was easy to hide or show chunks of HTML. For example: Different stages of a form, depending on what the user had entered.

Hiding or showing `<div>`/`<asp:Panel>`s was very simple, but in PHP all I can think to do is put my HTML into an `echo` statement. This makes the HTML very difficult to read, difficult to maintain and the whole file looks rather messy.

I'm positive there must be a better way of hiding or showing chunks of HTML without having to involve an `echo` statement, but I can't find any online documentation that explains how.

Thanks for any tips, advice or links to good PHP resources for this level of problem.

Comment: Wow. I've come a long way since I asked this question X-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Considering PHP as an embedded language you should, in order to get better readability, use the specific language forms for the "templating".

Instead of using echo you could just write the HTML outside the `<?php ?>` tags (never use `<? ?>` which could be misleading).

Also it is suggested to use `if () :` instead of `if () {`, for example:

```
<body>
    <?php if (true) : ?>
        <p>It is true</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</body>
```

References:

- [Alternative syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: I have never seen this, very neat.

Comment: I've just read the referenced link. I see that Alternate Syntax is not required, but is useful for readability. I think I'll do it this way, thanks!

Comment: I think this syntax `if():` vs. `if(){` is a matter of preference. I personally find the brace notation much easier to read and my IDE highlights it nicely for me.

Comment: @scunliffe, with a big amount of code finding what `}` is referring to is very hard, while a `endforeach;` totally explains this.

Comment: again, a matter of *personal preference*. ;-)  I also find that `endif`, `endforeach`, `endwhile` etc. remind me of the horrible practice of end brace commenting like: `}//end if` plus if I change my foreach to a while I don't need to edit my closing syntax to match.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to put the HTML into an `echo` statement.  Think of the HTML as implicitly being `echo`ed.  So, for conditionally showing a chunk of HTML, you'd be looking for a construct like this:

```
<?php
    if (condition == true) {
?>
    <div>
        <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

So the HTML string literal that exists outside of the PHP tags is just implicitly delivered to the page, but you can wrap logic around it to drive it.  In the above, the `div` and its contents are all within the scope of the `if` statement, and so that chunk of HTML (even though it's outside of the PHP tags) is only delivered if the condition in the PHP code is `true`.

Comment: @Django, for better readability you should use the alternative syntax, read my answer.

Comment: @Charliepiga: Agreed.  My syntax is a bit "exploded" for the purpose of showing each construct.  There are always different and often better ways to organize the code.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?php if ($var == true) { ?>
    <table>...</table>
<?php } ?>
```

You can use PHP tags like wrapped around HTML and based on the conditional the HTML will either be rendered or it won't.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your code is broken, I think. The third line should surely read: `<?php } ?>`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work too. E.g. for hiding/displaying a table tag.

```html
<table <?php echo (condition == true)?'visible':'hidden'; ?> ></table>
```